# copy else statement to if statement

Tags: reverse, smali, apktool

I am trying to copy the code of else state to the if statement.
In here I see `if-eqz` as the if condition but I don't know where the else condition is here. Can someone help me find else condition so that I can copy it to become the if code also.

I also want to know where is the start and the end of the else statement body

```
if-eqz v1, :cond_1

.line 103
:goto_1
return-object v0

.line 82
:cond_0
invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/Environment;->getExternalStorageDirectory()Ljava/io/File;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/io/File;->getAbsolutePath()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

.line 83
new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

invoke-virtual {v2, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

const-string v2, "/Android/data/"

invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

sget-object v2, Lcom/lingren/game/MonoJavaHelper;->s_Application:Landroid/app/Application;

invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/app/Application;->getPackageName()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

const-string v2, "/files/Res/AssistObj/"

invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

.line 84
const-string v2, "MonoJavaHelper"

new-instance v3, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

const-string v4, "ExternalStorageState Not UseAble:"

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual {v3, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

invoke-static {v2, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

goto :goto_0

.line 95
:cond_1
:try_start_1
invoke-virtual {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getFilesDir()Ljava/io/File;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/io/File;->getAbsolutePath()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

.line 96
new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v1

const-string v2, "/Res/AssistObj/"

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;
:try_end_1
.catch Ljava/lang/Exception; {:try_start_1 .. :try_end_1} :catch_0

move-result-object v0

goto :goto_1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [smali else to if modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585903/smali-else-to-if-modification)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. In this case, you should have edited your original question with the new information.

Answer (score 5):

Your example seems incomplete. For example it has `goto :goto_0` but doesn't contain the `:goto_0` label. In any event, the following example should help you to figure out how to handle your case. Smali code like the following:

```
if-nez v0, :cond_0

const-string v2, "hello 1"

:goto_0
return-void

:cond_0
const-string v2, "hello 2"
goto :goto_0
```

Corresponds to Java code like:

```
if (i == 0) {
    s = "hello 1";
}
else {
    s = "hello 2";
}
return;
```

The exact placement of `goto` statements and branches depends on compiler. Also for different conditions you may see `if-nez` or `if-eqz` or some other statements.